# Websphere MQ v7 - Security exits in Java?

Tags: java, security, ibm-mq, exit

According to [the Online IBM doc for WMQ 7](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm11171_.htm) it's possible to write channel security exits in the Java language, so I don't need to remember C programming and no worry about compiling for different operating systems.

My purpose is to write a security exit, which extracts the distinguished names (DN) on my QueueManager from a client certificate and forward its values as a JMS-usr property.

My problem: I even couldn't setup the provided example for my Server-connection channel. I tried to put the .class file of the IBM-example to the \exit folder, but my QM is throwing following error:

```
The dynamic loadable file  C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere
MQ\exits\MyMQExits.dll wasn't found.
```

Does this mean that I can't write security exits for Java for my QM-side (just in C / dll), only for client-applications??

Comment: The name of the page to which you linked is *Writing channel exits in Java **for WebSphere MQ classes for JMS***.  Shashi answered the question you explicitly asked and Roger preemptively answered the next one you would have asked once you got past the first problem.  What you want is a message exit and it must be written in C because that's what the QMgr uses.  Java exits are for use with the Java/JMS classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InfoCenter link may not be making it clear but the queue manager side exits must be developed in C language only. On the client side you can use Java/C to develop client side exits.

Answer (score 1):

> My purpose is to write a security exit, which extracts the
>   distinguished names (DN) on my QueueManager from a client certificate
>   and forward its values as a JMS-usr property.

Security exits are ONLY invoked for MQCONN/X and MQDISC MQ API calls.  That means that the security exit does NOT get access to any other MQ API call, hence, you cannot add message properties to a message.